# How define jQuery validate setDefaults

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-plugins

I have a problem with my code. I use jquery validate to validate my form. My question is how to run the setDefaults method? Because when looking at it in the debugger, I get an error like this: 
TypeError: jQuery.validator is undefined

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
            success : "valid"
        });
        $("#myForm").validate({
            rules : {
                "file1" : {
                    required : true,
                    extension : "slx|mdl",
                    accept : false
                },
                "file2" : {
                    extension : "m",
                    accept : false
                },
                "file3" : {
                    extension : "xlsx|xls",
                    accept : false
                },
                "file4" : {
                    extension : "pdf",
                    accept : false
                }
              }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setDefaults need a variable which must be used to validate in your case validator

just assign validator var to your validate method like this

```
var validator = $("#myForm").validate({
    rules : {
        "file1" : {
            required : true,
            extension : "slx|mdl",
            accept : false
        },
        "file2" : {
            extension : "m",
            accept : false
        },
        "file3" : {
            extension : "xlsx|xls",
            accept : false
        },
        "file4" : {
            extension : "pdf",
            accept : false
        }
      }
});
```

should work fine

Comment: I created a validator variable as you told me but it has not changed. It's always the same mistakes

Comment: The code works half well, but it can not check the file extensions. How to enable this feature?

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you added jquery validate lib correctly:

```html
<script src="jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```